# How to Draw UIImageView Frame in Red

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'd like to be able to draw my `UIImageView`'s frame in red so I can see it while I rotate and scale it. Setting the layer border width and color is not what I need because if I rotate it, it'll rotate the layer as well (whereas the `UIImageView` frame doesn't get rotated). Is this even possible? Anyone have any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

place it on a bigger UIView that has red background color.

```
UIView *redBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: … /* a bigger frame than imageView*/)];
[redBackgroundView: addSubview: imageview];
[self.view addSubview: redBackgroundView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add FramWork `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"`

```
UIImageView *imgReport = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20,250,150)] ;
    imgReport.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    imgReport.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0; // change cornerRadius as per you requriment
    imgReport.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imgReport.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    imgReport.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
 [self.view addSubview:imgReport];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the UIImageView to red using the backgroundColor property of that UIImageView object.